# Outputting Object to JSON instead of ID

Tags: json, django, django-queryset

In my Django project, my View is converting a `ValuesQuerySet` to a JSON string:

```
import json
# ...
device_list = list(Device.objects.values())
device_json = json.dumps(device_list)
```

The resulting JSON string:

```
[{"field1": "value", "location_id": 1, "id": 1, "field2": "value"},
 {...}]
```

How can I include the data within the location object represented by `"location_id": 1`, instead of the ID number? Something like this:

```
[{"field1": "value", "location_name": "name", "location_region": "region", "another_location_field": "value", "id": 1, "field2": "value"},
 {...}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can use [Field Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to follow relationships and access fields in another related model:

```
import json
# ...
device_list = list(Device.objects.values('field1', 'field2', 'location__name', 'location__region'))
json.dumps(device_list)
```

The resulting JSON string:

```
[{field1": "value", "field2": "value", "location__name": "name", "location__region": "region"},
 {...}]
```